# An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated + For some users

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, login

Recently we have configured FBA for our SharePoint application.
We are a facing strange issue.

FBA users are able to login into system. **Except for couple of users.**
Checked the ULS for users having issue. got this error message '**An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The security token username and password could not be validated..**'

Is it that this could be due to their passwords are incorrect...?

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in the past (but on the win auth) some users were facing login issues, but different each time. In my case the message was that password was incorrect. In the end we trace the issue to one of the DC controllers that had issue with time sync and was out by 2 minutes which was enough to invalidate request and record confusing message about the password.

You can run `W32tm /monitor /domain:yourdomain.com` from PowerShell or cmd to verify time sync of your DCs from Sharepoint server.